# TypeError: descriptor 'tick' for 'pygame.time.Clock' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to write a game with Pygame, but when I try to use the tick code, it stops working. Here is my code:

```py
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import QUIT

pygame.init()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
pygame.display.set_caption('Warrior Pre-1.0')
pos = 0
while True:
    DISPLAYSURF.fill("red")
    #pygame.draw.rect(rect())
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.Clock.tick(40)
```

I tried checking the Pygame docs, but I copy the code across and it does not work. Here is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\main.py", line 16, in <module>
    pygame.time.Clock.tick(40)
TypeError: descriptor 'tick' for 'pygame.time.Clock' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object
```

Comment: You should be creating an *instance* of the `pygame.time.Clock` class (during the initialization of your program), and calling `.tick(40)` *on that instance*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to utilize `pygame.time.Clock` goes like this:

```py
clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # initialize the clock before the main loop, usually after creating the display surface

while True:
    clock.tick(40)  # call `tick` on the initialized `Clock` object
    ...
```

Also since `pygame-ce` version `2.1.4` the `pygame.Clock` alias is also available for use so in this version you could simply have `clock = pygame.Clock()`, see the docs [here](https://pyga.me/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)

More about `pygame-ce` can be read here: [Pygame: Community Edition Announcement](https://www.reddit.com/r/pygame/comments/1112q10/pygame_community_edition_announcement/)